# Displaying number of int datatypes in a column using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Hello i'm new to coding python and using a dataset(csv file) to get knowledge on pandas. I need to output number of int in a given column of the file. i have tried using

**com.str.extract('(^\d*)')**
to code but it is displaying integers in between the strings

then i used

**com.str.extract('(^\d*$)')**

which displays pure int , but i dont know how to display number of ints that appeared in that column

[image: sample data]

Comment: Could you provide a sample data and expected output? I'm not sure if giving you an answer on any arbitrary data would help you.

Comment: Hello i have included the sample data in the main description and i want an output like this
<class 'str'>    899
<class 'int'>    21
so kindly help me out

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you do have a column of mixed dtypes, you could apply the build int `type()` function to the column and then use `value_counts()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1.1,2.2,3.3],['foo','man','chu']],columns=['one','two','three'],dtype='object')

   one  two three
0    1    2     3
1  1.1  2.2   3.3
2  foo  man   chu
```

---

```
df.one.apply(type).value_counts()
<type 'str'>      1
<type 'float'>    1
<type 'int'>      1
```

Comment: i ran your code using my dataframe('com' is my df) but it just throwed me that there are strings in the column

output
<class 'str'>    105119
Name: companyName, dtype: int64